# Infinispan JMX error

Tags: java, jmx, infinispan

Hello I'm getting following error:

`ERROR JmxUtil - ISPN000034: There's already an cache manager instance registered under 'org.infinispan' JMX domain. If you want to allow multiple instances configured with same JMX domain enable 'allowDuplicateDomains' attribute in 'globalJmxStatistics' config element`

My question is where and how can i configure this option programmatically and is there a method to unregister the cacheManager from JMX so this error will not occur everytime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can allow multiple cache managers to register in the same JMX domain with

```
new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().globalJmxStatistics().allowDuplicateDomains(true)
```

However, if you have multiple cache managers active at a time, you should ideally configure a different domain for each of them with

```
new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().globalJmxStatistics().jmxDomain("domain")
```

Also, make sure you call `cacheManager.stop()` when you stop using a cache manager to unregister its MBeans from JMX.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try this.